# Is a vector space isomorphic to the kernel $\oplus$ image of a map out of it?

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $f:V\to W$ be a linear map of finite-dimensional vector spaces. By simply counting dimensions and using rank-nullity, it is clear that $V\cong \mathrm{im}\,f\oplus\mathrm{ker}\,f$. I want to know if this holds on general vector spaces.

In fact, the first isomorphism theorem tells us that $\mathrm{im}\,f\cong V/\mathrm{ker}\,f$. Now consider $V/\mathrm{ker}\,f\oplus \mathrm{ker}\,f$. For every equivalence class in $V/\mathrm{ker}\,f$, fix a representative. Then $([x],k)\mapsto x+k$ is a bijection, so it seems $V\cong  V/\mathrm{ker}\,f\oplus \mathrm{ker}\,f\cong \mathrm{im}\,f\oplus\mathrm{ker}\,$.

In order to pick a representative in each class, it seems Choice is required to find a choice function on $V/\mathrm{ker}\,f$. Does this require the full strength of Choice, or is it weaker?

Comment: what do you mean by $\text{im} \  f \oplus \text{ker}$?

Comment: Do you mean to say $V/\text{ker} \ f \oplus \text{ker}  \ f \cong \text{im} \ f $?

Comment: According to Asaf from a post three years ago ([link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482947/can-a-vector-subspace-have-a-unique-complement-in-absence-of-choice)), the axiom of choice is equivalent to subspaces having direct complements.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas OP means img+ker as an external direct sum presumably.

Comment: @arctictern: Well, not according to me. More in accordance with general literature about the axiom of choice and vector spaces.

Comment: Speak of the devil. Well, I am not familiar with the general literature, and you were the first thing I found from google. As the comments in the link suggested, maybe you really are Freddy Kruger. :-)

Comment: @arctictern: At present time I cannot confirm nor deny any knowledge of involvement in such activities.

Comment: Note that $([x], k) \mapsto x + k$ is a bijection, but not necessarily a linear transformation! However, the title of this post is true. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/908233/711748.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this requires the full strength of the axiom of choice. The proof goes through the following theorem.

> The following are equivalent of $\sf ZF$.
>
> 1. The axiom of choice.
> 2. If $V$ is a vector space, and $W\subseteq V$, then $W$ has a direct complement in $V$.

Now it's easy, because given any $W$, consider the obvious map from $V$ to $V/W$, $V\simeq W\oplus V/W$, this means that $W$ has a direct complement. Therefore the axiom of choice must hold.

In particular, if the axiom of choice fails, then $V\simeq\ker f\oplus\operatorname{im} f$ must fail for some $V$ and $f$.

Comment: Would countable or dependable choice be enough if we restrict the dimensionality of $V$? If yes, how much do we have to restrict it (e.g. countable choice for countable dimension)?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right. You want to choose fibers for the quotient map. So you probably need something like countable choice if the image has a countable dimension.